# Prolog for Beginners

Tags: prolog

I'm new to prolog and have a rookie question:

Suppose I have these lines of code:

```
p(1).
p(2):-!.
p(3).
```

and I am running `p(X)`.

The question: I'm getting `X=1 , X=2`.
Why does `X` not equal `3` as well?

Comment: Because of the cut operator !. Try experimenting by placing cut operator ( ! ) in first predicate for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Prolog program is a sequence of statements, called clauses, of the form

```
P0  :-  P1, P2, …, Pn.
```

So to help you understand  your problem you have to know this:

Each of  `P0, P1, P2, …, Pn` is an atom or structure.
A period terminates every Prolog clause

**Declarative meaning:**

“`P0` is true if `P1` and `P2` and … and `Pn` are true”

**Procedural meaning:**

“To satisfy goal `P0`, satisfy goal `P1`
then `P2` then … then `Pn`”.

- P0 is called the head goal of a clause.
- Conjunction of goals `P1, P2, …, Pn` forms the body of the clause.
- A clause without a body is a fact:
  “`P.`” means   “`P is true`” or “goal `P is satisfied`”
- A clause without a head
  “`:- P1, P2, …, Pn.`”     or     “`?- P1, P2, …, Pn.`” is a query interpreted as
  `“Are P1 and P2 and … and Pn true?”`  or
  “Satisfy goal P1 then P2 then … then Pn”

The Cut clauses contain the "!" symbol (also pronounced bang). When the Prolog interpreter sees the cut symbol, it deletes the remaining rules that have the same positive literal as the rule that contains the bang. This can have several effects on the programs—it can represent certain negative results, it can avoid or deal smoothly with failures, or it can simply eliminate part of the search space and speed up the program.

Comment: You haven't described the cut operator, which is the whole point of his question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation , so if i understood correctly , in my case it is a Declarative meaning and '!' is cut symbol ?

Comment: Inotik here is a good learning material that helped me when I was studying PROLOG. http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse43

Answer (score 1):

the cut "!" is executed before p(3)... that is why it does not display X=3...

Comment: While the answer is correct, it certainly does not warrant an answer. However, it is obvious that the question does not necessarily know what the cut operator is. To make this a quality answer that might benefit others, perhaps you could elaborate on that?